# Focus on list item on down arrow press

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, html-lists

I am creating a custom auto suggest-box I need to move on `li` items on arrow down press.

so I added tabindex attribute to li it is getting focus. but problem is that it scrolling the div up with some random height that it out the selected li from div.

[image]

**after arrow down key:**

[image]

**and after some arrow-down key press:**

[image]

and after that it goes out of screen while mouse down behave perfectly.

Here I made a [Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/1/)
first click `item1` and then press arrow down it behaving same.

Comment: see if this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/38zR3/3/

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/9/

Comment: sorry, this supports tabbing as well http://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/14/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Elaborating on my comment**

Set the container's `scrollTop` to `index of focused li` * `li height`.

`return false` upon keydown to prevent normal browser scrolling of overflown parent.

```
$('div.container').on('focus', 'li', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass();
    $this.closest('div.container').scrollTop($this.index() * $this.outerHeight());
}).on('keydown', 'li', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (e.keyCode === 40) {        
        $this.next().focus();
        return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {        
        $this.prev().focus();
        return false;
    }
}).find('li').first().focus();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/42/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using anchor instead of tabindex? e.g

```
<li><a href="#"></li>
```

In my experience some browsers cannot handle the focus on tabindex correctly

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like that once and solved it by setting the CSS style `overflow` of the containing div to `none` or `hidden` depending on your preference.

Comment: thanks... that work correctly but cant change that is requirement to show scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to make sure it is either centered or how you want it to be.