# Using arrow keys on filtered "ul" list

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, filter, keyboard

I have a specific need for my website, which would make my life and those of my co-workers slightly easier :)

I use a little script that I found on this site to filter a list of "li" inside a "ul" anchor, based on user input :

HTML :

```
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" /> 

<ul class="navList">
    <li><a href="#">apples</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">apricots</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">acai</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blueberry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bananas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cherry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">coconut</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">donut</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">durean</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
$('#box').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis == ""){
        $('.navList > li').show();           
    } else {
        $('.navList > li').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
   };
});
```

This works quite well, but I would REALLY appreciate to be able to use arrow keys to select the result that I want, and then press Enter to trigger the link. Right now, I have to use the mouse, but I like everything to be smooth and convenient :)
To be more specific : Google style => when I type something, I like to be able to select what I'm proposed with the keyboard.

Here is the jSFiddle of the (modified) script that I use :
http://jsfiddle.net/Q83f2/115/

Thanks for your help !
Please tell me if I wasn't clear enough (and sorry for my eventual mistakes, english is not my native language).

Comment: why do you have the same script 2 times?

Comment: Woops, it's late, wasn't paying enough attention :). Fixed.

Comment: I can tab to the results in the JSFiddle you supply, and then enter to go to the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Focus on list item on down arrow press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929117/focus-on-list-item-on-down-arrow-press)

Comment: Yes, I found this topic already, but this doesn't correspond to my needs.. Maybe it can be tweaked to do what I want, but I than I'd need a little help for that. Concerning your first answer, tab works well ! But I find it not intuitive, I'd really like to use the arrow keys instead. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I think this script that can help inspire:

```
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" /> 

<ul class="navList">
    <li><a href="#">apples </a></li> //note the space after any words
    <li><a href="#">apricots </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">acai </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blueberry </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bananas </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cherry </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">coconut </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">donut </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">durean </a></li>
</ul>
```

simply by adding the library jquery ui, autocomplete

```
var g=$('a[href="#"]').text();
    var array=g.split(' ');
    $( "#box" ).autocomplete({
      source: array,
        change: function() {
            var sel=$('#box').val();
            if (sel.length == 0){
                $('li').removeAttr('style');
            }
            else{
            $('li:not(:contains("'+sel+' "))').attr('style','display:none;');
            }
        }
    });
```

download the library and insert it http://jqueryui.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I can effectively use the arrow keys to navigate now, but this doesn't work as I would expect. What I would like is the "li" lines to be filtered automatically on type, not to be displayed in a separate "popup" under the input field. Is it possible with this code ? I'm sorry, I'm really new to jQuery and I do my best to understand it. EDIT : the actual jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Q83f2/117/