# Send focus to dynamic li with jQuery

Tags: jquery, setfocus

I was wondering if you can send focus to a dynamic li. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I've got a search box that has a keyup function bound to it where it searches for people's names. The results appear in a div right below the search box with a ul of results. I was hoping to make it where if someone hits the down arrow button that the focus gets switched to the first element of the ul. Kind of like how a drop down works. Here's the code (I didn't put in all the CSS so it doesn't look as pretty as it should--just FYI)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search_name').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 40){
   //It does get here, and does find the li, BUT doesn't send the focus
   $('#search_results').find('li:first').focus();
   return ;
  }
        //This is the function that displays the UL in #search_results
      /*delay_call(function(){
      searchNameDept();
     }, 500 ); */
 });
});
```

```css
#search{
  position: relative;
  right:0;
  margin:0 1em;
  width:350px;
}
#search{
  top:0;
  z-index:10;
}
#search_name{
  
  display:block;
  padding:10px 50px 10px 10px;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
}
#search > a{
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color: #ec9507;
}
#search > a i{
  color:#fff;
}
#search_results{
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#search_results ul{
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#search_results li{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  transition:all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
  cursor:pointer;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
#search_results li:hover, #search_results li:focus{
  color:#fff;
  background-color: #27c7f4;
}
#search_results li i{
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" class="boxy" id="search">
  <input type="text" name="search_name" id="search_name" class="boxy" value="DIRECTORY" autocomplete="off" />
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="center_flex">Search</a>
  <div id="search_results">
    <!-- Example content that is printed out after searchNameDept() is run -->
    <ul>
      <li class="search_org">Sally Joe</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried $('#search_results').find('li:first').focus(), $('#search_results').find('li:first').trigger('focus'). Nothing works. Anyone have any feedback?

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929117/focus-on-list-item-on-down-arrow-press

Comment: I did see that form. I just couldn't even get it to set focus or even acknowledge that it was focus. If I use Firebug and try to do the focus, it worked just fine. But jQuery? Didn't want to do it. :(

Comment: $cbloss793: what is the purpose of giving focus to the first li element? is it only for styling? If so, you can create a CSS class with appropriate styling for the li element and toggle it as you go.

Comment: @zeropoint, there are functions that fire when you click. It searches for the employees in the orgchart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to just play with CSS & some jquery here.
here is your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7h0pavzb/ need to add a class to show that it is selected.

your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search_name').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 40){
            if($("#search_results li.active").length!=0) {
                var storeTarget = $('#search_results').find("li.active").next();
                $("#search_results li.active").removeClass("active");
                storeTarget.focus().addClass("active");
            }
            else {
                $('#search_results').find("li:first").focus().addClass("active");
            }
            return ;
        }
    });
});
```

and the style what i append is,

```
#search_results li.active { background:#000; color:#fff; }
```

here is another fiddle for up and down arrow key. https://jsfiddle.net/7h0pavzb/1/

Comment: That was it! Every time I tried to even change the focus(), the focus was still on the input box. THANK YOU for this!!

Comment: @cbloss793 this works fine. But it doesn't navigate to url when I click enter

Comment: @JohnyBravo I didn't want it to navigate to a URL, I wanted it to change what's in the search box. It would then fire off another function. Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [jQuery's .focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) documentation

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`). In
>   recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all
>   element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property.
>   An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key,
>   or by mouse clicks on the element.

So simply add `tabindex="10"` attribute to your `<li>` tags so they can be focused. Or you can also wrap the LI's content into `<a href="#"></a>`, as links are focusable elements.

Another way to achieve this result would be by simply adding a class to your "focused" `<li>` tag.

Comment: Hey @mjorissen, thanks for your feedback!

I will have to checkout the tabindex again or the a tag again. I did try both but it wasn't working.

Comment: I tried on a jsFiddle, here it is. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a72trr26/)
It works for me on latest versions of Safari and Firefox for Mac, but it may not work on older browsers.

Comment: @cbloss793 Also the method of adding a class proposed by @ameenulla0007 is better, because it is purely Javascript UX and doesn't depend on browser version, though the `<a>` method is more handy (then you have to focus on the `<a>` tag which is in the `<li>`, and not on the `<li>` itself).

Answer (score 0):

Just try below solution.

Hope it helps.

```js
 $('#productname').keydown(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == 38 || key == 40) {
var storeTarget = "";

if (e.which == 40) {
  if ($("ul#suggestion-list li.active").length != 0) {
    storeTarget = $('#ul#suggestion-list').find("li.active").next();
    $("ul#suggestion-list li.active").removeClass("active");
    storeTarget.focus().addClass("active");
  } else {
    $('ul#suggestion-list').find("li:first").focus().addClass("active");
  }
  return;
}
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="addproduct">
  <table>
<tr>
  <td>Product Name:</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="" id="productname" placeholder="Product Name" size="40" />
  </td>
  <td> Quantity </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="QTY" size="3" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <ul id="suggestion-list"></ul>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: I'm a little lost with this. I'm curious as to why you need a suggested list on a product page.