# Move focus to Next "li" element neglecting all nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Menu having structure as below.

```js
$('html').removeClass('no-js');
// Add plus mark to li that have a sub menu
$('li:has("ul") > a').append('<span class="plusMark">+</span>');

Mousetrap.bind('down', function(e) {

  if ($(".manu-t").children("ul").children("li").children(":focus").length != 0) {
    //mentioned below What I have tried till now
  }

});
```

```css
#nav,
#nav ul,
#nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
  color: #000;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative;
}

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#nav>ul,
.fa {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#nav>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav>ul>li>a {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}

#nav>ul>li>a:hover,
#nav>ul>li>a:focus,
#nav>ul>li>a.js-openSubMenu {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

#nav>ul>li:hover>a,
#nav>ul>li:focus>a {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  color: #fff;
}

#nav>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

#nav>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#nav>ul>li>ul>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}

#nav>ul>li>ul>li:not(:last-child) a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
}

#nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}

#nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover,
#nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

#nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li:not(:last-child)>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
}


/* Javascript classes */

#nav .js-hideElement {
  display: none;
}

#nav .js-showElement {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="containe-header">
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-t"><a href="#">Main</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-l"><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The question is to move focus from Item1 to Item2 and to Item3 so on...by pressing down arrow key (I have used Mousetrap library for detecting keypress)

What I have tried so far..

1.

```
var focused_index = 1;
focused_index=focused_index - 1;
$('a').eq(focused_index).focus();
```

But this method focuses on nested elements means from item1 to Sub Item 1 and then to Sub Item 2 and so on..

2.

```
// Get the focused element:
var $focused = $(':focus');

// No jQuery:
var focused = document.activeElement;

// Does the element have focus:
var hasFocus = $('foo').is(':focus');

// No jQuery:
elem === elem.ownerDocument.activeElement;
```

but this causes problem with other elements having focus inside Body tag.

3. Answer from this question [Send focus to dynamic li with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094120/send-focus-to-dynamic-li-with-jquery)

So how I can I move focus from Item1 to Item2.

Comment: Given your html structure: `$('a').eq(focused_index).closest("li").next().find("a").first().focus();`

Comment: FYI, `bind` is old syntax and has been deprecated. Look at `on`.

Comment: @freedomn-m I had tried that code but it is moving focus to Menu2. Not to next "li" element. Please help me solve this issue and thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @isherwood I agree, but you'll see this happens a lot on SO (perhaps not on the other overflow sites) as people like me want to provide help but don't have time for a fully fleshed answer.  Brief answers attract downvotes.  The counter-argument is of course "don't answer if you don't have time".

Comment: You asked: "So how I can I move focus from Item1 to Item2." - as there's no "menu" it looks like "item2"/"menu2" are the same - your current focus is on "item1" (the `<a>`) so it goes that you would want to focus on "item2" (the next `<a>`) - you also can't focus on `li` elements.  Maybe you can explain exactly what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: I have not posted whole css nor whole js, so menu is not showing properly here. But I want to Focus on <a> element of Item2. and then to <a> element of Item3.

Comment: Ah - sorry, my comment above uses your code `$("a").eq(focused_index)` which assumed your `focused_index` would change - if you're not changing the index then try: `$('a:focus').closest("li").next().find("a").first().focus();`

Comment: Not getting focus as expected and misbehaves with other body elements, but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to focus on  element of Item2. and then to  element of Item3.

You can use:

```
$("a:focus").closest("li").next().find("a").first().focus();
```

Working snippet:

```js
// Add plus mark to li that have a sub menu
$('li:has("ul") > a').append('<span class="plusMark">+</span>');

// set initial focus
$("#nav>ul>li.menu-t>ul>li>a:first()").focus();

$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
     $("a:focus").closest("li").next().find("a").first().focus();
     return false;
  } 
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
     $("a:focus").closest("li").prev().find("a").first().focus();
     return false;
  }
  
  //if ($(".manu-t").children("ul").children("li").children(":focus").length != 0) {
    //mentioned below What I have tried till now
  //}

});
```

```css
a { text-decoration: none; }
:focus { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="containe-header">
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-t"><a href="#">Main</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-l"><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This works perfect as expected. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS selector to store the elements you want to "focus" on in an array. Add an event handler for 'keydown' events - if the `e.code` shows that the user clicked the down arrow then iterate to the next element in the array. I did this by using a generator function that will rotate back to `0` index when we reach the end of the array:

```js
function* nextElGenerator() {
  var liEls = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-t > ul > li > a:first-child');

  var i = 0;

  while (true) {
    yield liEls[i];
    i += 1;

    if (i === liEls.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}

const bulletElItr = nextElGenerator();
let curEl;

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code === 'ArrowDown') {
    if (curEl) {
      curEl.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }
    curEl = bulletElItr.next().value;
    curEl.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="containe-header">
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-t"><a href="#">Main</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-l"><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```