# at end of list scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large unordered list. When the list has focus I can use the arrow keys to move up and down the list, however when I get to the last link if I press the down arrow again I need it to return focus to the first link. Also if I'm on the first link and press to up arrow I need it to focus the last link.

I have tried playing around with first child and last child, but can't work out how to do it. Any help would be most appreciated.

I have a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tlm2408/fbw9a2z5/2/) to play around with.

I've tried quite a few things, here is one example:

```
$("ul li a:last-child:after")$(this).parents('li').find('a:first-child');
```

Comment: *.oO(... Some readings about [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/) has been skipped. ... )* **Too broad!**

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette Sorry I'm just starting to learn jQuery. I can't wrap my head around it properly yet.

Comment: [Chat?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145750/jquery-very-basics)

Comment: This is very similar to [Focus on list item on down arrow press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929117/focus-on-list-item-on-down-arrow-press), except you also want to check the current selected item with the last one and then go to the first if they match. jQuery has a .`last()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, highly recommend that your check out the [learn.jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/) site.

As for a solution:

Building off the answer in [Focus on list item on down arrow press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929117/focus-on-list-item-on-down-arrow-press), which already will scroll through all the items. What you need to do is check if the currently selected item is the last. jQuery has the `.last()` method, which, when you give it an array of elements it will return the last one. In that example, it's also putting a class of `active` onto the currently selected element, so you just need to check if the last item has the class "active", which you can do with:

`$("li").last().hasClass("active")`

Then, if that's true, you want to select the first item. jQuery also has `.first()` which does the opposite of what `.last()` does. So you want to select the first element with:

`$("li").first().focus();`

Keep in mind, that in the code example when an element is "focused" it gets the class "active" applied to it.

Working solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/766/

If you want to do the opposite, when someone gets to the top automatically go to the bottom, just put the opposite code into the section of the "if key up" (which is key code 38).