# Angular 4 focus on item on arrow down and scroll

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, keyboard-events

I have items in the div *ngFor loop which applies css class 'message-list-active' on the selected message.

app.html

```
 <div  id="listText" *ngFor="let message of messages; let i=index" activeIndex = i" 
   [ngClass]="{'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }">
      {{message.name}}
 </div>
```

component.ts //listen for keyboard event using arrow up and down to select message

```
  messages;  // we have date stored here
  activeIndex = 0;


  @HostListener("document:keydown", ['$event']) 
   doSomething(event: KeyboardEvent): void {


  if (event.code == "ArrowUp" && this.activeIndex > 0) {
    this.activeIndex--

   }
  if (event.code == "ArrowDown" && this.activeIndex < this.messages.length-1) {
    this.activeIndex++

  }
 }
```

app.css

```
    #listText {
        width: auto;
        height:100%;
        overflow: auto
      }

     .message-list-active {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px 15px 5px 13px;
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: #CDE6F7;
        border-style: dotted;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted;
         }
```

And the problem is when selected message comes to the end of the list it will not scroll. So what I am trying to achieve is to have the selected item always focused and be able to scroll down and up:

Also similar example here:

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve this was answered using jquery jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/42/, [similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929117/focus-on-list-item-on-down-arrow-press) but how can I achieve this in Angular 4 using typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so fixed it by making a custom directive [focused]

app.html

```
     <div id="listText">
        <div *ngFor="let message of messages; [focused]="i === activeIndex" let i=index" activeIndex = i" 
          [ngClass]="{'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }">
       {{message.name}}
  </div>
```

Focused.directive:

```
  import {Directive, Input, Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'

  @Directive({
   selector: '[focused]'
     })

 export class FocusedDirective {

      @Input()
      set focused(value: boolean){
         if(value){
           this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scrollIntoViewIfNeeded');
         }
    }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}
   }
```

Comment: Renderer is deprecated in Angular 4, I believe.

Comment: @Jun711  I did same for horizontal, now when the active pointer passes the screen width, it didn't scroll the page. Any help in that would be appreciated.

Comment: AlexFF1 I am not able to keep it in focus, can you please share more code

Comment: @AlexFF1 i resolved , there is issue in syntax
```<div [appSearchfocus]="i === arrowkeyLocation" *ngFor="let resource of global_resources.concat(agency_resources) | searchResource: message; let i=index" arrowkeyLocation = i [ngClass]="{'active': arrowkeyLocation === i  }" (click)="onItemClick(user_id, resource)" (keydown)="keyDown($event)" >```

this work for me.

Comment: @AlexFF1 how can i hit click event when i tap `enter` and open active list item

Comment: @AnshulRiyal you mean you want to run a method onItemClick() when you hit ENTER?

Comment: @AlexFF1 yes, i used .click() in that element. Thanks.
BTW is there any other way around to do this `Focus scroll` thing rather than creating directive. just for curiosity.

Comment: @AnshulRiyal try (keyup.enter)="onItemClick(user_id, resource)",  or (keydown.enter), yes its possible without a directive, but I think its good to have as a directive, you can re-use it and your code will be cleaner

Comment: @AlexFF1 just found out `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` doesn't work for fireFox or Edge browser.

Comment: Fixed with polyfills `https://gist.github.com/hsablonniere/2581101`

Answer (score 2):

It will looking something like this:

```
private scrollTo(_index: any) {
  let elmnt = document.getElementById(_index);
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
   window.scrollTo(0, 0); // only if it's innerhtml
}
```

This will ensure that ever item that's focus will be into view.

In html need to do something like:

`id={{item.uniqueID}} (focus)="scrollTo(item.uniqueID)"` Make sure to make it unique for everything that uses this function.

**EDIT**

Try an in html: `id="list{{i}}"`

```
if (event.code == "ArrowUp" && this.activeIndex > 0) {
    this.activeIndex--
    let str = `list${this.activeIndex}`;
    let elmnt = document.getElementById(str);
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but I can't seem to get a focus on the div element

Comment: The arrow down or up should trigger the focus hmm.

Comment: yes I tried unique id, its just the (focus) event div not triggered when I select the div/message..

Comment: Made an edit. Not 100% sure if the html id will work but should be possible in maybe a different format.